# Supporting Multiple Screens -tablet with low resolution support

Tags: android, android-layout

I already read the [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) & also refer many SO questions.
but I'm still not sure what is the proper way.

I am develop the application only for Tablet.

I have the following folders,

- layout
- layout-large
- layout-xlarge

Also In the manifest file, I have definied the followings,

```
<supports-screens 
android:largeScreens="true" 
android:anyDensity="true" />
```

If screen resolution greater than 800 * 480 -> application working properlly

**My problem,**

I tested the same application in china based device with 503 * 320 resolution,

It doesn`t works properly.

Please, tell me how to solve this issue.Thanks.

**Update:**

Tablet with high resolution,

[image]

Tablet with low resolution,

[image]

home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/layout_light_background">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_dine_in"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="100dp"
    android:paddingRight="100dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/dineIn"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_delivery"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:padding="20dp"

    android:text="@string/delivery"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_collection"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_delivery"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="@string/collection"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_previous_orders"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn_delivery"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_delivery"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn_delivery"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn_delivery"
    android:layout_marginBottom="71dp"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="100dp"
    android:paddingRight="100dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/previousOrders"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_delivery"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="                  " />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/sampleRestaurantName"
    android:textSize="@dimen/restaurantNameFontSize"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAssignDriver"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn_collection"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn_collection"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_previous_orders"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="100dp"
    android:paddingRight="100dp"

    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/assignDriver"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Currently all of the three folders contains same xml file..

layout/home.xml title is **Normal**

& layout-large/home.xml title is **MyRestaurant**

Comment: `I get alignment issue.` - this is as descriptive as `it doesn't work`. Which issue exactly? Can you provide screenshots? Can you provide your layout?

Comment: thanks for reply..I give now.

Comment: this unfortunately needs to be solved 1 by 1 for each case. layout by layout. provide one of the cases. screen shot and xml code. most probably the mistakes you did are repeated everywhere. so you can do a fast fix.

Comment: @hasan83 I give layout & screenshot now

Comment: @hasan83 see my update

Comment: do you support multi-language in your app. like do you support right to left language? do you have translations or just english?

Comment: do you try to reverse the direction of your layout when you have a rtl language direction?

Comment: currently not-support multi-language

Comment: try the solution I provided below then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85299/discussion-between-ranjith-and-hasan83).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I just found it.

Font size from device to device differs for devices with different resolutions when setting text appearance.

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
```

Since `previous orders` is a long sentence it didn't fit in its button. because its button width equals to the `delivery` button width. and because left and right padding is so large 100dp the space left for text is small. thats why the button increased its height cause height is wrap content.

Comment: change the text on the previous button to a smaller one and you will see that.

Comment: also you need to change the text on assign driver. if that confirmed you can fix accordingly

Comment: same result..text appearance is not my problem,my problem is low quality tablet(china based).this tablet resolution is 503 * 320 pixels.. this is my problem

Comment: my application only for tablets. but low resolution tablets return this problem:(

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is the problem remove the left and right padding on the previous driver and assign driver buttons and you will see.

Comment: yes..after remove padding it works correctly..my doubt why 7 inch tablet refer this file -> layout/home.xml... all other high resolution tablets are refer the layout-large/home.xml.

Comment: large small etc is for screen size not resolution. but, hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi etc for resolution

Answer (score 1):

Since your app. doesn't support language directions. you don't have to include the attributes with `end` and `start`.

Those will affect the layout appearance if device language direction is different than you expected. which is the language you tested your app on. "English"

Remove everything that have the words `end` and `start` in it as:

```
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
```

and others. do that and check the results.

Comment: exactly same results?\